# tabBar app launches very slowly on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, device

I have a tab bar based app that runs like a charm on simulator and tested on instruments, the app contains 6 tabs, the first one that is been loaded contains only 8 round rect buttons (with a little png image on each one, image size is very small), each button when touched (up inside) will display a diferent view controller. each one of the other tabs contains a table view except for a one that contains a webView that loads a 25 MB PDF file. However, when I try to test the app on iphone device (iphone 1st genration the one that is before 3G, that runs ios 3.0.1) that app takes around a minute to load, how come that ??? what is the reason for this weird problem ?

Comment: From where you load that pdf? From network? Did you use multi threading?

Comment: it's bundled inside the app, i do not use multithreading because it's kinds difficult to implement for me (don't really know how to use it), anyway, the pdf file is not loaded when the app first runs, it only loads when its tab is selected only.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's because you're loading a 25MB PDF file. This is huge for a 1st generation iPhone.

Comment: but there are many heavy apps and games on that device that runs without slowness, the pdf is not loaded when the app first runs, it loads only when its tab is selected

Comment: Maybe, but these apps probably have a special way of managing their resources. Also, if your PDF is bundled into the application it makes sense that the slowness occurs at launch time. Try to replace it with a 50K PDF and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because the simulator uses your computer's resources, for it a 25mb pdf file might be nothing whereas it porbably is a huge strain for the iphone with its limited resource count. As has been stated above,try it with a smaller pdf , it should be much much faster on the iphone.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the PDF to something that is tiny, 100KB maybe and see if it is still doing that. If not then it is due to the fact that the app is trying to load the PDF when it runs. Remember that the device may also be scanning the app to see what is in the bundle and that could also slow it down. Never the less, a 25MB PDF is far too large to have on any device, even a computer. Trying loading it on a computer zooming right in and scrolling about, it will undoubtably lag.

If you want to reduce the size of the PDF, use the Quartz Filter that comes in Preview as this should really reduce the file size.

Comment: I can't find Quartz filter in preview .. where is it exactly ?

Comment: ah, I found it ... i've reduced its size, but i lost the quality, all words are not clear at all now, is that usual with Quartz filter ?

Comment: Yes that is usual. I think it is simply chancing all the text and objects in the PDF to lower quality images, hence hugely reducing the file size. You can of course create you own quartz filter. Look here [link](http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/quality-reduced-file-size/)